# "toLocaleDateString"を使っての"和暦"の移動速度が重い原因について、など。

Tags: javascript

下記のコードは、アナログ時計の外周を、1分ごとに"和暦"と"西暦"に切り変わるものですが、
問題箇所が2点あるのです。

1点目は、暦は"toLocaleDateString"を使っていますが、西暦に比べて和暦の方が重い(遅い)
のです。原因は、何でしょうか。
移動速度(step)は、0.06に設定してあります。

2点目は、仮に現在が"平成99年(9999年)だとすると、来年は"平成100年(10000年)"となり、
文字数が1つ増えます。このように"和暦"や"西暦"の年の桁が増加するごとに、1文字抜け落ちて
表示されます。
この問題を解決するには、コード内の『var TodaysDate = "     ";』の"     "内のスペースを
増やすだけでいいのですが、何か式を使ってできないでしょうか。

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>１分おき日英切り替え</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){
    "use strict";

function $(sel)
{
    return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel)
{
    if (typeof document.getElementsByClassName === 'undefined')
    {
        return document.getElementsByName(sel);
    }

    return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}


var dCol = '00ff00', //date colour.
    sCol = 'ff0000', //seconds colour.
    mCol = '000000', //minutes colour.
    hCol = '000000', //hours colour.
    fCol = '0000ff', //face color
    ClockHeight = 40,
    ClockWidth = 40,
    ClockFromMouseY = 0,
    ClockFromMouseX = 100;

var TodaysDate = "     ";

  /*最大文字数を5文字に設定(""内に半角で、5文字分スペースを作る)。*/


var D = TodaysDate.split('');
var H = '...';
    H = H.split('');
var M = '....';
    M = M.split('');
var S = '.....';
    S = S.split('');
var Face = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12',
    font = 'Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    size = 1,
    speed = 0.6;
    Face = Face.split(' ');
var n = Face.length;
var a = size * 10;
var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0,
    scrll = 0,
    props = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + fCol + '">';
var Split = 360 / n;
var HandHeight = ClockHeight / 4.5; 
var HandWidth = ClockWidth / 4.5;
var HandY = -7,
    HandX = -2.5,
    step = 0.06,
    currStep = 0,
    y = [],
    x = [],
    Y = [],
    X = [],
    Dy = [],
    Dx = [],
    DY = [],
    DX = [];

var i;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    y[i] = 0;
    x[i] = 0;
    Y[i] = 0;
    X[i] = 0;
}

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++) 
{
    Dy[i] = 0;
    Dx[i] = 0;
    DY[i] = 0;
    DX[i] = 0;
}

var wrapper = $('clock');
var html = '';



// Face wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    html += '<div class="Face" name="Face" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props + Face[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Hours wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Hours" name="Hours" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + hCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + H[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Minute wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Minutes" name="Minutes" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + mCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + M[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Seconds wrapper
html = '';
for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
{
    html += '<div class="Seconds" name="Seconds" style="position:absolute;width:16px;height:16px;font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;color:' + sCol + ';text-align:center;font-weight:bold">' + S[i] + '</div>';
} 
$('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

// Mouse move event handler
function Mouse(evnt) 
{
    if (typeof evnt === 'undefined')
    {
        ymouse = event.Y + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = event.X + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
    else
    {
        ymouse = evnt.clientY + ClockFromMouseY;
        xmouse = evnt.clientX + ClockFromMouseX;
    }
}
document.onmousemove = Mouse;

function ClockAndAssign() 
{

var date = new Date(),
    mt = date.getMinutes();

      if( mt%2==0 ){


var date = new Date();

    TodaysDate = date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");

 }     else{


    TodaysDate = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).replace(/\u200e/g, "") + "年";

  }

    var D = TodaysDate.split('');
    var props2 = '<span style="font-family:' + font + ';font-size:' + size + 'em; color:#' + dCol + '">';
    var Dsplit = 360 / D.length;

// Date wrapper
html = '';

for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++){
    html += '<div class="Date" name="Date" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0;height:' + a + ';width:' + a + ';text-align:center">' + props2 + D[i] + '</span></div>';
}
$('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;


    var time = new Date();
    var secs = time.getSeconds();
    var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
    var mins = time.getMinutes();
    var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
    var hr = time.getHours();
    var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(time.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
    $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var F = $$('Face')[i];
        F.style.top = y[i] + ClockHeight * Math.sin(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        F.style.left = x[i] + ClockWidth * Math.cos(-1.0471 + i * Split * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < H.length; i++)
    {
        var HL = $$('Hours')[i];
        HL.style.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll;
        HL.style.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(hrs);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < M.length; i++)
    {
        var ML = $$('Minutes')[i].style;
        ML.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(min) + scrll;
        ML.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(min);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < S.length; i++)
    {
        var SL = $$('Seconds')[i].style;
        SL.top = y[i] + HandY + (i * HandHeight) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll;
        SL.left = x[i] + HandX + (i * HandWidth) * Math.cos(sec);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < D.length; i++)
    {
        var DL = $$('Date')[i].style;
        DL.top = Dy[i] + ClockHeight * 1.5 * Math.sin(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180) + scrll;
        DL.left = Dx[i] + ClockWidth * 1.5 * Math.cos(currStep + i * Dsplit * Math.PI / 180);
    }
    currStep -= step;
}

function Delay() 
{
    scrll = 0;
    Dy[0] = Math.round(DY[0] += ((ymouse) - DY[0]) * speed);
    Dx[0] = Math.round(DX[0] += ((xmouse) - DX[0]) * speed);
    for (i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        Dy[i] = Math.round(DY[i] += (Dy[i - 1] - DY[i]) * speed);
        Dx[i] = Math.round(DX[i] += (Dx[i - 1] - DX[i]) * speed);
    }
    y[0] = Math.round(Y[0] += ((ymouse) - Y[0]) * speed);
    x[0] = Math.round(X[0] += ((xmouse) - X[0]) * speed);
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.round(Y[i] += (y[i - 1] - Y[i]) * speed);
        x[i] = Math.round(X[i] += (x[i - 1] - X[i]) * speed);
    }
    ClockAndAssign();
    setTimeout(Delay, 20);
}

Delay();
}());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 「JavaScript/HTML/CSSスニペット」を使ってコードを入力していただけると、読者もその場で実行できて返答できるかもしれません。style.top / style.left の値に単位 'px' を付けないと Google Chrome 
 では動かないようです。

Comment: Mac上でChrome,Firefox,Safariで試してみましたがが、とくに和暦が遅くなることは観測できませんでした。

Comment: Chrome等では、和暦は重くならないのですか。IEでは、重いのです。

Comment: すみません。bodeliタグ内にjavascriptがあるため、セクションごとにうまく分けられませんでした。

Comment: IE11とEdgeで和暦が重いことを確認しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1点目

`date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", ...)` が IE11 と Edge で尋常でなく遅いですね。`toLocalDateString` を1000回呼ぶ時間を計ってみました。

IE11:
ja-JP-...: 63086 [ms]
en-US: 697 [ms]

Edge:
ja-JP-...: 84628 [ms]
en-US: 577 [ms]

Chrome:
ja-JP-...: 1092 [ms]
en-US: 811 [ms]

Firefox:
ja-JP-...: 908 [ms]
en-US: 594 [ms]

IE と Edge では ja-JP-... の方が en-US にくらべて**90〜160倍**も時間がかかっています。

分が変わっていなければ前回使った文字列を使い回す、などの処理で`toLocalDateString` を呼ぶ回数を減らすしかないと思います。

### 2点目

class="Date" の要素数を `toLocalDateString` の結果から動的に決めればよいです。`DX`, `DY`, `Dx`, `Dy` の要素数も動的にする必要があります。問題は文字数が長くなったときに参照すべき座標の値が存在しないことで、こういう場合は最後の要素の座標を採用するなどで調整するといいかもしれません。

ざっと書き換えたコードを掲載します。関数 `updateYear()` のあたりが両方の問題に対処しています。

```js
"use strict";

function $(sel) {
  return document.getElementById(sel);
}

function $$(sel) {
  return document.getElementsByClassName(sel);
}

function setPosition(element, y, x) {
  element.style.top = y + 'px';
  element.style.left = x + 'px';
}

const CLOCK_HEIGHT = 40,
    CLOCK_WIDTH = 40,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y = 0,
    CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X = 100;

const H = '...'.split('');
const M = '....'.split('');
const S = '.....'.split('');
const SPEED = 0.6,
    FACES = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12'.split(' ');
const HAND_HEIGHT = CLOCK_HEIGHT / 4.5; 
const HAND_WIDTH = CLOCK_WIDTH / 4.5;
const HAND_Y = -7,
    HAND_X = -2.5,
    STEP = 0.06;

var ymouse = 0,
    xmouse = 0;
var currStep = 0;
var lastBasePositions = [];

function initialize() {
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastBasePositions[i] = {x:0, y:0};
  }

  var html = '';
  // Face wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Face">' + FACES[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Of').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Hours wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Hours">' + H[i] + '</div>';
  } 
  $('Oh').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Minute wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Minutes">' + M[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Om').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Seconds wrapper
  html = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    html += '<div class="Seconds">' + S[i] + '</div>';
  }
  $('Os').children[0].innerHTML = html;

  // Mouse move event handler
  document.onmousemove = function(evnt) {
    ymouse = evnt.clientY + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_Y;
    xmouse = evnt.clientX + CLOCK_FROM_MOUSE_X;
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

var lastYearPositions = [{x:0, y:0}];
var lastYearString = ' ';
var lastYearLocale = '';
function updateYear(currentDate, scrll) {
  var yearString = lastYearString;
  if (currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0) {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'ja')
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "");
    lastYearLocale = 'ja';
  } else {
    if (lastYearLocale != 'en')
      yearString = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { era: "long", year: "numeric" }).
          replace(/\u200e/g, "") + "年";
    lastYearLocale = 'en';
  }

  var yearLength = lastYearPositions.length;
  if (yearString != lastYearString) {
    lastYearString = yearString;        
    var yearCharacters = yearString.split('');
    yearLength = yearCharacters.length;

    // Date wrapper
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
      html += '<div class="Date">' + yearCharacters[i] + '</div>';
    }
    $('Od').children[0].innerHTML = html;
  }
  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastYearPositions[0];
  positions[0].y = lastPosition.y + ((ymouse) - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
  positions[0].x = lastPosition.x + ((xmouse) - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  for (var i = 1; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    lastPosition = i < lastYearPositions.length ?
        lastYearPositions[i] :
        lastYearPositions[lastYearPositions.length - 1];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = lastPosition.y + (positions[i-1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED;
    positions[i].x = lastPosition.x + (positions[i-1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < yearLength; ++i) {
    var radian = currStep + i * (360 / yearLength) * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Date')[i],
                Math.round(positions[i].y) + CLOCK_HEIGHT * 1.5 * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                Math.round(positions[i].x) + CLOCK_WIDTH * 1.5 * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  lastYearPositions = positions;
  currStep -= STEP;
}

function ClockAndAssign() {
  var date = new Date();
  var secs = date.getSeconds();
  var sec = -1.57 + Math.PI * secs / 30;
  var mins = date.getMinutes();
  var min = -1.57 + Math.PI * mins / 30;
  var hr = date.getHours();
  var hrs = -1.575 + Math.PI * hr / 6 + Math.PI * parseInt(date.getMinutes(), 10) / 360;
  $('Od').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Of').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Oh').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Om').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  $('Os').style.top = window.document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrll = 0;

  var positions = [{}];
  var lastPosition = lastBasePositions[0];
  positions[0].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (ymouse - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
  positions[0].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (xmouse - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  for (var i = 1; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    lastPosition = lastBasePositions[i];
    positions[i] = {};
    positions[i].y = Math.round(lastPosition.y + (positions[i - 1].y - lastPosition.y) * SPEED);
    positions[i].x = Math.round(lastPosition.x + (positions[i - 1].x - lastPosition.x) * SPEED);
  }
  lastBasePositions = positions;

  var split = 360 / FACES.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < FACES.length; ++i) {
    var radian = -1.0471 + i * split * Math.PI / 180;
    setPosition($$('Face')[i],
                positions[i].y + CLOCK_HEIGHT * Math.sin(radian) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + CLOCK_WIDTH * Math.cos(radian));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < H.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Hours')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(hrs) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(hrs));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < M.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Minutes')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(min) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(min));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < S.length; ++i) {
    setPosition($$('Seconds')[i],
                positions[i].y + HAND_Y + (i * HAND_HEIGHT) * Math.sin(sec) + scrll,
                positions[i].x + HAND_X + (i * HAND_WIDTH) * Math.cos(sec));
  }
  updateYear(date, scrll);
  requestAnimationFrame(ClockAndAssign);
}

initialize();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.Face {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  widdth: 10;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #0000ff;
}

.Hours {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Minutes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Seconds {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ff0000;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.Date {
  position: absolute;
  height: 10;
  width: 10;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
    <div id="Od" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Of" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Oh" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Om" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Os" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px">
        <div style="position:relative">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 詳しい回答をありがとうございました。コードが様変わりしていて面くらいましたが、希望通りに動きました。和暦は、更新させる箇所のClockAndAssign() {}内で重く、他の箇所で設定すると軽いのです。

Comment: 分からない点がありましたので、教えていただけませんでしょうか。回答のコードは、条件式で和暦と西暦に切り替えるように設定されていますが、和暦だけの設定する場合は、どのように書き換えればいいでしょうか。

Comment: 1分ごとに切り替える箇所を"   if (currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0)  "とし、"lastYearLocale"の値をそれぞれ別のものにして、表示の"yearString"の値をそれぞれ『和暦(年・月・日・曜日)』の設定にすれば、和暦も重くなく，かつ午前0時に自動更新もされるはずです。

Comment: lastYearLocale のかわりに lastYear をグローバル変数として、lastYear と currenDate.getFullYear() を比較するようにします。

Comment: 上記の私のコメントの" if (currentDate.getMinutes() % 2 == 0) "を " if ( (currentDate.getFullYear())&&(currentDate.getMonth() + 1)&&(currentDate.getDate())&&(currentDate.getDay()) ) "風にして、"lastYearLocale "の呼び方を変えるということですよね。

Comment: 新しいコードで"const SPEED "は、0.6で設定されていますが、それより小さい値に設定すると、"face"の体裁が崩れてしまいます。この部分は、改良できるでしょうか。質問からそれましたが、ちょっと気になりましたので、コメントしました。

Comment: この質問の主題と関係ない問題ですので、新たに質問を作ったほうがよろしいかと思います。