# Date#toLocaleDateStringで和暦を扱う場合、西暦を扱う場合と比較してパフォーマンスが落ちてしまう問題を解決したい

Tags: javascript, css

下記のコードは、１分ごとに"和暦"と"西暦"に切り替わる『(カレンダー機能付き)デジタル時計』で、
マウスポインターの動きに合わせて付いて行くものですが、問題があるのです。
更新させると、西暦に比べて和暦の移動速度が極端に遅くなる(重くなる)のです。
ブラウザは、IE11です。
この重さの問題を解決したいのですが、コードをどのように書き換えればいいのでしょうか。
以前にも同じ質問をしたのですが、別コードのためにコードの組み立てができません。
分かる方は、教えていただけないでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>文字マウスストーカー</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: black;}

#myText {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'comic sans ms', verdana, arial;
    color: gold;
    position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 3000;cursor: default;
}
#myText div {position: relative;}
#myText div div {position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;text-align: center;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
/* Circling text trail- Tim Tilton
 Website: http://www.tempermedia.com/
 Visit: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for Original Source and tons of scripts
 Modified Here for more flexibility and modern browser support
 Modifications as first seen in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/
 username:jscheuer1 - This notice must remain for legal use
 */

;(function(){

    var msg = "";
    var size = 24;
    var circleY = 0.75; var circleX = 2;
    var letter_spacing = 5;
    var diameter = 10;
    var rotation = 0.4;
    var speed = 0.3;

    if (!window.addEventListener && !window.attachEvent || !document.createElement) return;

    msg = msg.split('');
    var n = msg.length - 1, a = Math.round(size * diameter * 0.208333), currStep = 20,
        ymouse = a * circleY + 20, xmouse = a * circleX + 20, y = [], x = [], Y = [], X = [],
        o = document.createElement('div'), oi = document.createElement('div'),
        b = document.compatMode && document.compatMode != "BackCompat"? document.documentElement : document.body,

    mouse = function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        ymouse = !isNaN(e.pageY)? e.pageY : e.clientY; // y-position
        xmouse = !isNaN(e.pageX)? e.pageX : e.clientX; // x-position
    },

    makecircle = function(){ // rotation/positioning
        if(init.nopy){
            o.style.top = (b || document.body).scrollTop + 'px';
            o.style.left = (b || document.body).scrollLeft + 'px';
        };

        currStep -= rotation;

        for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){ // makes the circle
            d = document.getElementById('iemsg' + i).style;
            d.top = Math.round(y[i] + a * Math.sin((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleY - 15) + 'px';
            d.left = Math.round(x[i] + a * Math.cos((currStep + i) / letter_spacing) * circleX) + 'px';
        };
    },

    drag = function(){ // makes the resistance

        var date = new Date();
        var mt = date.getMinutes();

        if( mt%2==0 ){

            var date = new Date(),
                m = new Array("１月", "２月", "３月", "４月", "５月", "６月", "７月", "８月", "９月", "10月", "11月", "12月"),
                w = new Array("?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?", "?"),

                month = m[date.getMonth()],
                day = date.getDate(),
                week = w[date.getDay()],

                Hour = date.getHours(),
                Min = date.getMinutes(),
                Sec = date.getSeconds();

            if(Min <= 9) { 
                Min = "0" + Min; 
            }
            if(Sec <= 9) { 
                Sec =  "0" +  Sec; 
            }

            var option = { year: '2-digit' };

            t = date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", option).replace(/\u200e/g, "").replace(" ", "") +
                " " + month + day + "日" + " " + week + " " + Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;

        }else{

            var date = new Date(),
                w = new Array("Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"),
                m = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"),

                day = date.getDate(),
                week = w[date.getDay()],
                year = date.getYear() + 1900,

                Hour = date.getHours(),
                Min = date.getMinutes(),
                Sec = date.getSeconds();

            if(Min <= 9) { 
                Min = "0" + Min; 
            }
            if(Sec <= 9) { 
                Sec =  "0" +  Sec; 
            }

            if((day == 1)||(day == 21)||(day == 31)){
                day=day+ "st";
            }
            else if((day == 2)||(day == 22)){
                day=day+ "nd";
            }
            else if((day == 3)||(day == 23)){
                day=day+ "rd";
            }
            else{
                day=day+ "th";
            }

            t = " " + week + " " + day + " " + m[date.getMonth()] + " " + year + "◆" + " " +  Hour + ":" + Min + ":" + Sec;

        }

        var currentLength = msg.length;

        // 状態の変更
        msg = t.split('');
        n = msg.length - 1;

        // 文字要素の変更
        for (var i = Math.max(currentLength, msg.length) - 1; i > -1; --i)
        {
            var d = i < currentLength ? document.getElementById('iemsg' + i) : null;

            if (d)
            {
                if (i < t.length)
                {
                    // 既存要素の内容変更
                    d.innerHTML = msg[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    // 不要になった要素の削除
                    d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // 不足要素の追加
                d = document.createElement('div');
                d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
                d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
                d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
                oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
            }
        };

        y[0] = Y[0] += (ymouse - Y[0]) * speed;
        x[0] = X[0] += (xmouse - 20 - X[0]) * speed;

        for (var i = n; i > 0; --i){
            y[i] = Y[i] += (y[i-1] - Y[i]) * speed;
            x[i] = X[i] += (x[i-1] - X[i]) * speed;
        };

        makecircle();
    },

    init = function(){ // appends message divs, & sets initial values for positioning arrays

        if(!isNaN(window.pageYOffset)){
            ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
            xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
        } else init.nopy = true;

        for (var d, i = n; i > -1; --i){
            d = document.createElement('div'); d.id = 'iemsg' + i;
            d.style.height = d.style.width = a + 'px';
            d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg[i]));
            oi.appendChild(d); y[i] = x[i] = Y[i] = X[i] = 0;
        };

        o.appendChild(oi); document.body.appendChild(o);
        setInterval(drag, 25);
    },

    ascroll = function(){
        ymouse += window.pageYOffset;
        xmouse += window.pageXOffset;
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
    };

    o.id = 'myText'; o.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

    if (window.addEventListener){
        window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
        document.addEventListener('mouseover', mouse, false);
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouse, false);

        if (/Apple/.test(navigator.vendor))
            window.addEventListener('scroll', ascroll, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent){
        window.attachEvent('onload', init);
        document.attachEvent('onmousemove', mouse);
    };
})();

// -->
</script>
</head>

<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE11で試してみましたが、遅くなりませんでした。ブラウザ以外の要因があるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: Windows 10 + IE11 で試してみましたが確かに和暦になるとCPU使用率が上がって遅くなりますね。計測してみたところ、date.toLocaleDateString("ja-JP-u-ca-japanese", option) の部分で45ms程度かかっていました。IE11ではこのメソッドが遅いのかもしれません。和暦変換を自前でやれば西暦表示と同程度にはなるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43328/tolocaledatestring%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E5%92%8C%E6%9A%A6%E3%81%AE%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%8C%E9%87%8D%E3%81%84%E5%8E%9F%E5%9B%A0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9/43337#43337 問題自体はこちらに書いてあるとおりなので、これはほとんどコーディング依頼ですね。

Comment: もとのコードは http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex13/circletext_dev.htm これでしょうか。「username:jscheuer1 - This notice must remain for legal use」という部分を消してはいけません。

Comment: そのコードのようです。個人的にカスタマイズして楽むつもりでしたが、ここは公の場ですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以前の質問と全く同じ問題で、和暦に切り替える条件もまったく変わっていませんので、[以前の回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/43328/tolocaledatestring%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AE%E5%92%8C%E6%9A%A6%E3%81%AE%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E9%80%9F%E5%BA%A6%E3%81%8C%E9%87%8D%E3%81%84%E5%8E%9F%E5%9B%A0%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9/43337#43337)と同じように解決できます。

- 状態を表現する変数を作る
  最後に表示した日付がどのロカールだったかを、グローバル変数などに保持します。前回のコードの `lastYearLocale`
- 最後に表示したデータを保持する変数を作る
  `toLocaleDateString()`の結果を使い回すために、最後に表示した日付をグローバル変数などに保持します。前回のコードの `lastYearString`
- 状態が変わったことを検知して、それぞれの変数を更新する
  前回のコードの `updateYear()` の最初のブロック

Comment: 回答をありがとうございました。回答の論法は、下記のサイトの質問文で試していますが、画面に表示されません。どこが間違っているのでしょうか。https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/44276/%e5%a4%89%e6%9b%b4%e3%81%ab%e3%82%88%e3%82%8a%e5%8b%95%e4%bd%9c%e3%81%97%e3%81%aa%e3%81%8f%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9fjavascript%e3%81%ae%e3%83%87%e3%83%90%e3%83%83%e3%82%b0-%e4%bf%ae%e6%ad%a3%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95%e3%81%8c%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84

Comment: 和暦の重さの問題は、解決しました。しかし、新たな問題が生じましたので、質問に出します。